# SQL: How can I group by consecutive years?

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table 'movies' with the field 'Year', 'movieId', 'movie_running_time', 'Director'...etc.

I want to select the data that show the average running time of movies per group of 4 consecutive years (ie for the years 2001-2004, 2005-2008,...). The result displays the MIN and MAX year for each group, and the avg running time converted into hours and minutes.

The group of years is expected to exclude Year 0 and start at the minimum year 2001 (2001-2004, 2005-2008,...)

Table: movies

| movieId | Year | movie_running_time (minute) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2002 | 88 |
| 2 | 2004 | 118 |
| 3 | 2001 | 86 |
| 4 | 2008 | 110 |
| 5 | 2008 | 113 |
| 6 | 2008 | 89 |
| 7 | 2007 | 119 |
| 8 | 2006 | 103 |
| 9 | 2001 | 86 |
| 10 | 2002 | 117 |
| 11 | 2006 | 101 |
| 12 | 0 | 0 |
| 13 | 2007 | 111 |
| 14 | 2001 | 105 |
| 15 | 2005 | 134 |
| 16 | 2003 | 86 |
| 17 | 0 | 0 |
| 18 | 2003 | 93 |
| 19 | 2005 | 119 |
| 20 | 2003 | 110 |
| 21 | 2004 | 99 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Expected result:

| Year(MIN) | Year(MAX) | AVG(movie_running_time) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | 2004 | 1:38 |
| 2005 | 2008 | 1:51 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Comment: How do the groups start? Do they start at 2001 specifically, or is it based on the minimum year in the table? What is the table you posted(it doesn't seem to match the column you describe as either your existing table or your expected output)? It would be best to post some same data and the result you expect.

Comment: Also, which DBMS are you using? e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL

Comment: And what units is your movie_running_time currently in if you want them converted to hours and minutes?

Comment: sorry it was not clear in the initial post.I'm using MySQL for practice.

The group is expected to start at 2001 and exclude Year 0 or separate as one group from other years.
And the unit of movie running time is minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are probably looking for something like

```
SELECT 
 min(year) minyear, 
 max(year) maxyear, 
 avg(movie_running_time)/60 avg_hours, 
 avg(movie_running_time)%60 avg_remaining_minutes
FROM movie
GROUP BY (year-2001)/4
```

This assumes your years and running times are integers (and that running time is in minutes), but you can adjust depending on your actual data and table structure.

I'm also assuming that it's okay to hardcode 2001 in your query (but you could get it from elsewhere if you want).

The idea of the `group by` is that, for integer division, you will end up with a floor. So 0/4, 1/4, 2/4, 3/4 are all 0 (your first group), 4/4, 5/4, 6/4, 7/4 are all 1 (your second group) and so on.

The idea of the integer division and modulus in the `select` statement is that once you have your average (say 70 minutes), 70/60 is 1 hour (because integer division uses a floor), and 70%60 is the remaining 10 minutes.

Here's a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nIQZpc17) of the basic idea.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! It's a lot clear for me!

Comment: @amber_the_debutant Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. If you need more/different information, please clarify